# How to create a function that check multiple values passed as an argument

Tags: php

I want to create a function that checks if the variable is empty or not. I'm using empty to check it is empty or not. but I want to make a function where I can pass the fields I want to check whether they are empty or not and that returns true or false. any idea how can I do this?

```
function isInputEmpty($username, $email, $password) { // etc
    return empty($inputName); // I want to check here for the variables that I pass in function
}
```

Comment: I check it like this: `if(empty($var)){}`

Comment: @N3x I also do it like that but I want the function to check the variables passed as an argument automatically & return True or False

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array and loop over it :

```
<?php
$inputs = [
    'username' => 'foo',
    'password' => '', // <-- something empty
    'email'    => 'bar'
];


function isInputEmpty($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        if (empty($value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$isEmpty = isInputEmpty($inputs);

if ($isEmpty)
    echo "empty";
else
    echo "not empty";
```

This outputs

> empty

---

If you don't want to bother with arrays, you can use [func_num_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [func_get_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) to pass an undefined number of arguments :

```
<?php
$username = 'foo';
$password = ''; // <-- something empty
$email = 'bar';


function isInputEmpty()
{
    for ($i = 0, $len = func_num_args(); $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        if (empty(func_get_arg($i)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$isEmpty = isInputEmpty($username, $password, $email);

if ($isEmpty)
    echo "empty";
else
    echo "not empty";
```

This outputs

> empty

Comment: The only issue I can foresee is if the OP passes something like `$_POST` through as the array and attempts to validate checkboxes or radio buttons from a form. If no checkboxes are checked the *index* doesn't exist in the `$_POST` array so won't be evaluated in the loop... that's their gotcha to look out for though.

Comment: @CD001 yep, true. Feel free to edit my answer if you want to add this detail :)

Comment: They haven't given any indication that that's what they *are* intending to do (I was just inferring it from the names of the variables) - so your answer is spot on as-is ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `func_get_args()` to get multiple parameters, and then use loop + empty to determin if one of them is empty then return true or false.

Comment: can you please show a code example. will empty accept an array? it looks like `func_get_args` returns an array

Comment: yes, then you can loop the array use foreach or for,I think you can manage to do it